# How to combine from multiple probability in adaboost?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, roc, boosting, adaboost

I tried to implement adaboost, then I want to create ROC and count for the AUROC. I use tree as my base classifier. I got the probability from each tree. How to combine them?

[image: Simplicity]

For simplicity, there are two models and their alpha (weight) for each classifier. How to combine the probability so I can count the AUROC?